# 2 rectangles and 1 square

Tags: trigonometry, rectangles

I need a solution in algebraic form. I have $2$ rectangles and $1$ square. $2$ rectangles are place vertically to each other and horizontally in front of the square. I need to scale them in a way that

1. All interim space between rectangles and squares is occupied
2. Square should not lose its aspect ratio(means it should remain square)
3. $2$ of the rectangles also retain their aspect ratios
4. However the height can be increased for both rectangles and square but they should aligned from top and bottom.

I have a rough design 
[image]

Comment: That's simple! just scale the rectangle with less horizontal length to that of bigger and finally scale the square to fit to both

Comment: This way the bottom may not be aligned. The height of sum of 2 rectangles's height and height of square should be equal.

Comment: So... do it.  Just scale the square to be equal to the height of the two rectangles.  There's no reason that is an issue.

Comment: Okay, so if rectangle 1; is $5 \times 7$ and rectangle 2: is $6\times 3$.  Well scale scale rectangle $2$ but $\frac 56$ to get rectangle 2': $5 \times 3*\frac 56= 5\times \frac 52$.  The height to the rectangles are $7$ and $\frac 52$ so the height of the square must be $7 + \frac 52 = 10\frac 12$.  So.... make the square $10\frac 12 \times 10\frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

Rectangle 1: is $a \times b$

Rectangle 2: is $c \times d$

And square 3: is $e\times e$.

So .... scale:

Keep triangle 1: to be $a \times b$

Scale rectangle 2': so that the width $c$ scales to $a$.  That is scale by $\frac ac$.  So rectangle is $a \times d*\frac ac$ or $a \times \frac {da}c$

And the side of the square: The heights of the rectangles are $b$ and $\frac {da}c$.  So the side of the square needs to be $b+\frac {da}c$..... so make it $b+\frac {da}c$.

Answer (score 0):

This requires the solution of two linear equations in two variables.

1. Rectangle 1: width $w$, height $h$
2. Rectangle 2: width $W$, height $H$
3. Square: side $S$

One wishes to scale the two rectangles by factors $x$ and $y$ such that

1. $wx=Wy$
2. $hx+Hy=S$

So solve

\begin{eqnarray}
wx-Wy&=&0\\
hx+Hy&=&S
\end{eqnarray}
for $x$ and $y$

This is easily solved to give

$$x=\frac{WS}{wH+Wh}\qquad y=\frac{wS}{wH+Wh}$$

The entire result can then be scaled further by any factor required.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble of dealing with fractions until the end.

Suppose you have rectangles with (width-by-height) dimensions $a\times b$ and $c\times d$.

[image]

Get a common width by scaling the first rectangle with a scale factor equal to the full width ($c$) of the second, and then scaling the second rectangle with a scale factor equal to the full width ($a$) of the first.

[image]

The resulting rectangles have a combined height of $ad+bc$, which becomes the required side-length for your square.

From here, you can scale the entire figure however you like. In particular,

- If you are trying to hit a target width of $w$, scale by
  $$\frac{w}{ad+bc+ac} \qquad\left(=\frac{\text{target width}}{\text{total width}}  \right)$$
- If you are trying to hit a target height of $h$, scale by 
  $$\frac{h}{ad+bc} \qquad\left(=\frac{\text{target height}}{\text{total height}}\right)$$